# Error using Carrierwave in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have a website where it contains many users and each user have his own profile i want to let them upload there image through carrierwave gem but i get a loop with the following errors it is the first time i work with carrierwave gem :( :

```
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:22:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  request_store (1.2.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  rack-timeout (0.3.2) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:125:in `block in call'
  rack-timeout (0.3.2) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `call'
  rack-timeout (0.3.2) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `timeout'
  rack-timeout (0.3.2) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:124:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/server.rb:541:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/server.rb:388:in `process_client'
  puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
  puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `call'
  puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

here is the carrier wave gem :

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

and here is the profile model :

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :education_experiences
  has_many :working_experiences
  after_create :set_avatar_url

  validates :linkedin_url, format: { with: URI.regexp }, if: Proc.new { |company| company.linkedin_url.present? }
  validates :facebook_url, format: { with: URI.regexp }, if: Proc.new { |company| company.facebook_url.present? }
  validates :twitter_url, format: { with: URI.regexp }, if: Proc.new { |company| company.twitter_url.present? }
  validates :google_plus_url, format: { with: URI.regexp }, if: Proc.new { |company| company.google_plus_url.present? }
  mount_uploader :avatar_url,ImageUploader
  def set_avatar_url
    avatar_url if avatar_url.present?
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=100"
    self.update avatar_url: gravatar_url
  end

  def as_json(options={})
    {
        country_id: self.country_id,
        job_title: self.job_title,
        bio: self.bio,
        linkedin_url: self.linkedin_url,
        facebook_url: self.facebook_url,
        twitter_url: self.twitter_url,
        google_plus_url: self.google_plus_url,
        avatar_url: self.avatar_url,
        education_experience: self.education_experiences,
        working_experience: self.working_experiences
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Seem you didn't paste the whole stack trace. Where's the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to restart the server after gem instalation.